# problems with installing elementary os luna

Tags: dual-boot, elementary-os

i m trying to install elementary os in my sony vaio laptop e series sve15127cnb. it has preinstalled windows 8. i tried to install elementary os with dual boot with windows 8. i downloaded 64 bit version from this website http://elementaryos.org/ and made a bootable usb with unetbootin-windows-608 software. when i rebooted my pc got the following option 

`try elementary os
install elementary os
look for bad block(something like this)`

when i go in any of the options above i m only getting a blank screen and nothng else. i dont know wat to do? is this problem with some graphics or 64 bit. shall i try with 32 bit. because m getting only black screen and nothng else. what is the problem???????????

Answer (score 0):

A few things come to mind, though these are all shots in the dark until we get even a vague heading:

1. Did you let the boot process sit long enough? A blank screen might just be loading something silently. Anything over three or four minutes is probably grounds for concern, but if you rebooted after thirty seconds of blankscreen you might want to give it another go.
2. Did you verify the downloaded image? It's rare that a download or USB creation really goes wrong, but it may be worth verifying your checksums again.
3. Does your laptop have SecureBoot? I think that interferes with trying to load a "foreign" (relative to the Windows-laden laptop) operating system. If you do have SecureBoot (or other UEFI shenanigans) you will probably have to disable them to get anywhere.

Comment: i verified the download, i downloaded it from official site. and that black screen was more than 3-4 minutes. i have secure boot but it is already disabled